# Linux Kernel Oops (Call Trace) produced by a simple kthread code

Tags: c, linux-kernel

> **Operating System**: Fedora 26 Alpha (Server)
>
> **Kernel Version**: Linux kerneldev 4.13.0-rc5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 15 19:53:44 IST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
[root@kerneldev thread_k]# cat kernel_t.c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Neeraj Pal <neerajpal09@gmail.com>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Working Sample kernel Thread code");


static struct task_struct *t;
static int t_f(void *unused)
{
    while(1)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello world\n");
        ssleep(5);
    }

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Stopping thread\n");
    do_exit(0);
    return 0;
}

static int __init init_thread(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Thread creating ...\n");
    t = kthread_create(t_f,NULL,"mythread");
    if(t)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Thread Created Sucessfully\n");
        wake_up_process(t);
    }
    else
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Thread Creation Failed\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

static void __exit cleanup_thread(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning up ...\n");
}

module_init(init_thread)
module_exit(cleanup_thread)
```

Kernel Log:

- insmod module_name

`

```
[root@kerneldev thread_k]# dmesg
[ 3983.796253] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[ 3983.796270] kernel_t: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[ 4731.985703] Thread creating ...
[ 4731.986047] Thread Created Sucessfully
[ 4755.392992] Cleaning up ...
[ 4965.415410] Thread creating ...
[ 4965.415905] Thread Created Sucessfully
[ 4965.415909] do_init_module: 'kernel_t'->init suspiciously returned 1, it should follow 0/-E convention
               do_init_module: loading module anyway...
[ 4965.415911] CPU: 1 PID: 4465 Comm: insmod Tainted: P           OE   4.13.0-rc5 #1
[ 4965.415912] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS 1.10.2-1.fc26 04/01/2014
[ 4965.415913] Call Trace:
[ 4965.415920]  dump_stack+0x63/0x8b
[ 4965.415923]  do_init_module+0x8d/0x1e9
[ 4965.415926]  load_module+0x21bd/0x2b10
[ 4965.415929]  SYSC_finit_module+0xfc/0x120
[ 4965.415931]  ? SYSC_finit_module+0xfc/0x120
[ 4965.415934]  SyS_finit_module+0xe/0x10
[ 4965.415937]  entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x1a/0xa5
[ 4965.415939] RIP: 0033:0x7fab36d717a9
[ 4965.415940] RSP: 002b:00007ffcbf3e9478 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
[ 4965.415941] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000000230f9fd980 RCX: 00007fab36d717a9
[ 4965.415942] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 000000230f7f545c RDI: 0000000000000003
[ 4965.415943] RBP: 00007ffcbf3e9470 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007fab37033e80
[ 4965.415943] R10: 0000000000000003 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 000000231178d010
[ 4965.415944] R13: 000000231178e2f0 R14: 00007ffcbf3e9410 R15: 0000000000000006
[ 4965.416151] Hello world
[ 4970.523214] Hello world
[ 4975.643344] Hello world
[ 4980.763177] Hello world
[ 4985.883245] Hello world
[ 4991.003233] Hello world
[ 4996.123130] Hello world
[ 5001.243217] Hello world
[ 5006.363091] Hello world
[ 5011.483207] Hello world
[ 5016.603131] Hello world
[ 5021.723079] Hello world
[ 5026.843170] Hello world
[ 5031.963064] Hello world
[ 5037.083047] Hello world
[ 5042.203140] Hello world
[ 5047.323058] Hello world
[ 5052.443102] Hello world
[ 5057.563049] Hello world
[ 5062.683030] Hello world
[ 5067.803101] Hello world
[ 5072.923216] Hello world
[ 5078.043363] Hello world
[ 5083.163032] Hello world
[ 5088.282956] Hello world
[ 5093.403124] Hello world
```

`

- rmmod module_name

`

```
[ 5093.987294] Cleaning up ...
[ 5098.522923] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffffffc05eb023
[ 5098.522955] IP: 0xffffffffc05eb023
[ 5098.522979] PGD 21e0c067 
[ 5098.522980] P4D 21e0c067 
[ 5098.522989] PUD 21e0e067 
[ 5098.522997] PMD 31a5e067 
[ 5098.523006] PTE 0

[ 5098.523027] Oops: 0010 [#1] SMP
[ 5098.523037] Modules linked in: ip6t_rpfilter ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_conntrack ip_set nfnetlink ebtable_nat ebtable_broute bridge stp llc ip6table_nat nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_nat_ipv6 ip6table_mangle ip6table_raw ip6table_security iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack iptable_mangle iptable_raw iptable_security ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_filter ip6_tables snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul snd_timer crc32_pclmul 8139too ppdev ghash_clmulni_intel snd parport_pc floppy 8139cp soundcore pcspkr i2c_piix4 parport mii virtio_balloon nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd grace sunrpc xfs virtio_console libcrc32c qxl crc32c_intel drm_kms_helper ttm serio_raw drm virtio_pci virtio_ring virtio
[ 5098.523454]  ata_generic pata_acpi qemu_fw_cfg [last unloaded: kernel_t]
[ 5098.523641] CPU: 0 PID: 4467 Comm: mythread Tainted: P           OE   4.13.0-rc5 #1
[ 5098.523822] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS 1.10.2-1.fc26 04/01/2014
[ 5098.524024] task: ffff9c69b1af2640 task.stack: ffffb45740338000
[ 5098.524206] RIP: 0010:0xffffffffc05eb023
[ 5098.524378] RSP: 0018:ffffb4574033bef8 EFLAGS: 00010246
[ 5098.524552] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffffffc05ec024 RCX: 0000000000000000
[ 5098.524731] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000246 RDI: 0000000000000246
[ 5098.524936] RBP: ffffb4574033bf00 R08: 000000000000027e R09: ffff9c69b44300c0
[ 5098.525154] R10: ffffb4574033bee0 R11: 0000000000000281 R12: ffff9c69df7c61c0
[ 5098.525360] R13: ffffb45741e7fbc8 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff9c69b1af2640
[ 5098.525568] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9c69ffc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 5098.525781] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 5098.526002] CR2: ffffffffc05eb023 CR3: 000000005f5ac000 CR4: 00000000001406f0
[ 5098.526226] Call Trace:
[ 5098.526446]  kthread+0x125/0x140
[ 5098.526664]  ? kthread_park+0x60/0x60
[ 5098.526882]  ret_from_fork+0x25/0x30
[ 5098.527111] Code:  Bad RIP value.
[ 5098.527338] RIP: 0xffffffffc05eb023 RSP: ffffb4574033bef8
[ 5098.527564] CR2: ffffffffc05eb023
[ 5098.527787] ---[ end trace d4fb567953037a51 ]---
```

`

> I feel little bit difficulty in reading and understanding this kernel call trace.
>
> Why Kernel Oops or kernel panic here, is it a fault during kernel threading ?

Comment: Your __init function has no return in the success case.

Comment: Yes, sorry @stark , There is a `return` but I just found, after you guys told me to about `return` , that i forgot to apply closing braces before return.So, Accidentally, it makes `return` statement is in else block. Sorry Again.

Answer (score 1):

dude, cmon, how are you compiling this in the first place?

your init function does not have an explicit return statement for the success case and returns garbage

on exit you just allow the module to get unloaded, while the thread you created is left alone. then as the code it executes is removed (after the module is unloaded) you get the crash

the loop in the thread is `while (1)` which is wrong by design: there is no way to stop it. and it's definitely not how kernel threads are supposed to operate.

i strongly suggest you work on your basics in userspace

Comment: Yes Sorry.I solved problems of my code and found that for `return` there was a mistake of closing braces due to which it makes it in else block and also solved `while(1)` problem and in that i only initialize  `var = 1` and then in exit function `var = 0`. Main Problem is i ain't able to understand about Kernel oops . 

I know mistake is mistake but this kernel code is just a small sample code for learning kernel threads,that's why i didn't keep focus on small things.

Thanks for good suggestion and will work on it.But, sometimes this doesn't prove that basics are low. 

Believe me! :)

Comment: there is nothing special about the oops. "BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffffffc05eb023" means the cpu tried to access this area, but there is nothing there. presumably this is one of the places your module used to reside. RIP is 'instruction pointer' and it is equal to the faulting address, i.e. the cpu was executing code in that area. the backtrace is the standard for all kernel threads - they all are created in the same place. the rest is standard boiler plate.

Comment: i strongly suggest doing stuff in userspace for now because it is easier to debug. once you get more proficient the kernel will stop posing significant trouble (for the most part).

Comment: Yes, you are right.And I also know about basics of Linux Assembly x86 ,So i got little bit about kernel oops like registers , but unable to get about call trace , that's why little bit confused.

Professionally (In office), I am working on userspace development and also on debugging  .

I already read LKMPG and Linux Kernel Development by Robert Love.
And right now reading LDD3 but with theory i also focusing more on practical way , that's why i think about possibilities in userspace and want to achieve same in kernel level by experimenting .

Comment: That's why i don't keep focus on small things while writing some random testing code in kernel.But, you made me realize that in kernel level i need to focus on small things also. Really Thanks for that.



Now i create a global variable and reading and writing it from functions in thread level .So, i think if in future i also need some locking mechanisms to prevent it from race conditions  ?